# php zip file not getting all images

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to create a zip file of all the images that are stored in a database. This is done when the user clicks on a download button. Right now, you click on the download button, the zip file is created and the window pops up asking you if you want to open the file or save it to your computer. If you open the file, it shows you all the file names (like it's supposed to). The problem is, when you try to view the images, they are all the SAME image, just with different names.

Here's my code:

```
    /* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($files = array(), $destination = '', $overwrite = false) {
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
    //vars
    $path = 'admin/ReviewFiles/';
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach($files as $file) {
            //make sure the file exists
            $fullFile = $path . $file;
            if(file_exists($fullFile)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    //if we have good files...
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        //add the files
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file);
        }

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();

        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($destination);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

And here's where the function is called:

    $i = 0;
    $reviewFiles = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
        $reviewFiles[$i] = $row->fileName;
        $i++;
    }
    $zipCreated = create_zip($reviewFiles, 'reviewFiles.zip', true);
    $file = 'reviewFiles.zip';
if ($zipCreated) {
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reviewFiles.zip');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    readfile("reviewFiles.zip");
    exit;
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of to figure out why it's not actually downloading each image. So, I guess clearly put, my question is: How can I fix the code to make it actually zip each file, not just one image with the same image with different names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
if(file_exists($fullFile)) {
    $valid_files[] = $file;
}
```

should be:

```
if(file_exists($fullFile)) {
    $valid_files[] = $fullFile;
}
```

Otherwise the files could not be found. If you have changed this, you may also wish to set a local name:

```
foreach($valid_files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
}
```

I'm using [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to prevent zip from creating sub directories in the archive.